# i cannot find how to start eclipse IDE after install

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

i did a setup of eclipse IDE for my ubuntu19.04 x64.
disclaimer: i am not at all a java dev, but i need this IDE to run a project i work with locally an no one in the team can tell me how to do so without this IDE.

so i took an eclipse installer from the official website. "by Oomph", i chosed "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"

setup runs sucessfully, IDE launches, i did open my java project with it, fine.

but when i close the IDE i have no idea how to launch it again. Nothing useful is found in the head up display of ubuntu when i search for "eclipse".

the installed created a config folder in my user home folder, just containing a setup log.
But there is no executable here.
i don't get why they do something so hidden. Any other ide i tested is able to be launched from CLI by its name.

so if anyone is used to eclipse your advice would be welcome.

Comment: Got a folder /opt/eclipse or similar by chance? You should be able to just navigate there and execute the "eclipse" executable from there. 
I'm not sure if this is the default-location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh well, this Oomph installer is damn misleading.
It says that the install folder is 
*/home/$USER/eclipse*

but in reality, where i can find the executable is
*/home/$USER/java-2019-09/eclipse*

now i just have to add this folder to my $PATH variable in my .profile to be able to launch it from command line.

thank you all